# SocketException for closing a UDP Socket

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, xamarin.android

I have a library written in C# which I have used it in WP7/iOS/Windows Apps. It works with Mono because I am just using UdpClient and nothing more. Its an open source library to find peers automatically. You can find it at [salaam.codeplex.com](http://salaam.codeplex.com)

Now I am just trying to port my app to Android. When I found my peers, I just want to close the UDP connections and goto another activity but when I close the socket, despite the fact that I put it in a try catch phrase but it throws a `SocketException` and it exits.

What can I do to prevent that?

If you Finish the activity, it gives you that exception, if you call `SalaamBrowser.Close();` it's the same.

Exception text:

Unhandled Exception:
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: interrupted
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.ReceiveFrom_nochecks_exc (System.Byte[] buf, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags flags, System.Net.EndPoint& remote_end, Boolean throwOnError, System.Int32& error) [0x00000] in :0

at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.ReceiveFrom_nochecks (System.Byte[] buf, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags flags, System.Net.EndPoint& remote_end) [0x00000] in :0

at System.Net.Sockets.Socket+Worker.ReceiveFrom () [0x00000] in :0

Thanks

Comment: What is the text provided with the exception?

Comment: Unhandled Exception:
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: interrupted
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.ReceiveFrom_nochecks_exc (System.Byte[] buf, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags flags, System.Net.EndPoint& remote_end, Boolean throwOnError, System.Int32& error) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.ReceiveFrom_nochecks (System.Byte[] buf, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags flags, System.Net.EndPoint& remote_end) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket+Worker.ReceiveFrom () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0

Answer (score 0):

It is the receive that is throwing the exception, not the close. It is throwing it because you closed it. I don't know what else you could have expected.

Comment: Yeah but the problem is that I have covered it. I mean I put it in a try/catch phrase. and the fun part is that when I print outputs, it passes all those try(s) and nothing actually goes to catch. Plus this code is working just fine on WP7/iOS/Windows !

Answer (score 0):

The reason your `try/catch` doesn't work is that error is occurring outside of that block.

You are using `Async` transfer and upon closing the socket your receive delegate throws the exception.

You are terminating from the wrong point, do it from inside receive delegate.

What you are doing is like plugging out a computer instead of shutting it down.